# VBA to compare two dates then transfer data from one sheet to new sheet and relevant column

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have spent the past few days to a week browsing the net, and whilst I have come close to what I am looking for, with all due respect meant - me being a novice and all that, there seems to be a lot of code around but seems somewhat of an over kill to what I need.  So now, because I can't actually find what it is I am looking for, and whilst learning a few new things at the same time, I am now posting my question to see if I can find my answer.

Putting a side all in-cell If and vlookup statements - and so on, I have got pretty far in a project that I am working on, but have hit one small snag to complete it.

From initial data input to Macro's that do collect data in one sheet, then after print - harvests this data and then sorts in to a new order within a "Transfer" Sheet ready to move to the last sheet.

> Bridging a gap!

After doing everything so far myself, I need to be able to get one small piece of code together that now accesses the "Transfer" sheet, finds the date ("B6" [e.g. June-16]) and matches it against a corresponding one in another sheet "Annual" in row("B6:M6" [Jan-16:Dec-16]); the result would be;

Sub: lookup "Transfer"("B6")="Annual"("G6"), copy content "Transfer"("B9:B128"), paste "Annual"(G9:G128"). End

However, I think some of my problem is based on the level of automation the workbook is working on, for example: Transfer (B6) and Annual (B6:K6) dates are based on differing formulas (variables) resulting in the same (values [Jun-16 // mmm-yy)

Your help would be greatly appreciated

JohnH

Comment: Whilst Markos answer has been of some help, and it works to a point of completing the its cycle without error, it seems there could well be an issue hidden, I suspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John, please try the following:

```
Sub copyToTransfer()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngTarget As Range

Set rngSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Transfer").Range("B6")
Set rngTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Annual").Rows(6)

Set rng = rngTarget.Find(rngSource.Value, , xlValues)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(rngSource.Parent.Name).Range(rngSource.Offset(3).Address, rngSource.Offset(125).Address).Copy
    rng.Offset(3).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Else
    MsgBox "Date " & Format(rngSource.Value, "mmm-yy") & " not found in Annual sheet!"
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi Markos I have had a look at the code and ran it, everything marries up as per request and as you have laid it out very clearly too - and it seems to work, however, it comes back with Aug-16 not found in Annual sheet, when it is clearly there!  any further suggestions?

Comment: hi, please check what exact date is behind Aug-16, e.g. 31/08, 01/08 or any other. Dates must be exaclty the same in both sheets. MMM-YY format may be misleading.

Comment: Fair play.  Done that. Adjusted all dates to start on the 1st (01), all formats are now the same format of dd mmm yy so there's no confusion in the processing, and it flags up the same again!  Range ("B6") is right and Rows(6) is good, so there's no issue in the way code is processing its tags, as it gets to the end... but it's not identifying what it's looking for.  Out of interest; do you reckon it has something to do with - that its picking up on the formula behind the date, and not the value of the formula which the code suggests it's supposed to be doing?

Comment: As a sample test to see if it was the formula sat behind the value, i took out the formula and placed in the raw date of 01/05/2016 (formatted as, dd mmm yy), and it flags up the same again?

Comment: I changed the code to look in values - check if ok now.

Comment: Done that.  Along with the date still being 01/05/2016, I've also played with changing ("Annual").Rows(6) to ("Annual").Range("B6:M6") to see if it would throw anything else up.  It seems to be working through the code fine enough with any changes being made, but it's as if the "Annual" sheet is blank, when it's not?

Comment: there must be something with your spreasheet, formulas etc. You need to figure it out - i don't see anything can be changed in the code. Anyway, your question is so specifc then I doubt anyone else benefit.

Comment: Fair play. Thanks for you assistance so far Markos, I'll post any results here in a short while.

Comment: I've tried three different types of work books, and blank ones, taken all formulas out, and it keeps coming back with the same thing buddy!

Comment: As one last comment Markos and a heads up.  I had one last play with the coding, and changed one object:

>>Set rng = rngTarget.Find(rngSource.Text, , xlValues)

Now works as we both wanted! cheers Markos

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Markos answer has been of some help, and it works to a point of completing its cycle without error, it seems there could well be a issue hidden, so whilst I don't want badger him too much, I suspect it relates to one of two places;

> > Set rngTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Annual").Rows(6)
> >
> > Set rng = rngTarget.Find(rngSource.Value, , xlValues)

Whilst I could be wrong, the reason for this understanding is, that I have created three different workbooks, 1. as 97-03 version, 2. a plain 07 version and 3. 07-macro enabled version and all tests come back as; It finds its source and recognizes the date, but when looking at its target, it is staring at a blank page!  Is there anyone else that would like to contribute, or are able to identify the issue?

John

Comment: With a bit of exploring and trial and error... it's done! Cheers to Markos for your assistance.